# Cannot compare time in mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I have two drop downs which displays time from one we can select from time and another is for to time it displays time in following format

```
01:00 AM   09:00 AM

06:00 PM   07:00 PM
```

in my database i hace datetime field which keeps datetime in 2019-06-03 17:15:00 this format. I 
want if anybody selects a particular time range then those record should display but can't understand how to write the query for that because time in the dropdown is in different format (AM or PM)

Comment: You need to converse 7PM to 19:00:00 and compare with record in database.

Comment: try `date("g:i a", strtotime("2019-06-03 17:15:00 "));` in php. If you want to do it in JS its a bit more complicated.

Comment: how will i convert 7PM to 19:00:00

Comment: Or, alternatively, learn some HTML basics - and realize that the _submission value_ of a select option can be different from the _text_ you want to display …

Answer (score 0):

you most convert 7:00 PM to 19:00:00 for store in database

```
date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime("2019-06-11 07:00 PM"));
```

and when use it convert 19:00:00 to 7:00 PM

```
date("Y-m-d g:i a", strtotime("2019-06-11 19:00:00"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do in two steps:

```
$selectedTime = $_POST['time']; // suppose it contains 19:00:00
$currentDate  = date('Y-m-d');
$datetime = $currentDate.' '.$selectedTime;
$query = "select * 
          from tablename
          where fieldname M= '".$datetime ."'";
// query is "select * from tablename where fieldname <= '2019-06-11 19:00:00'";
```

Comment: i 'm comparing date like this $selectedFromTime = date("H:i:s", strtotime("2019-06-13 06:45:00"));
 $selectedToTime = date("H:i:s", strtotime("2019-06-13 09:00:00")); $this->db->where('start>=',$selectedFromTime);
 $this->db->where('end<=',$selectedToTime);   but it is not working